# How can I make the column filtering works in the datatables server-side processing?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, server-side

I'm using Datatables in OctoberCMS and I'm trying to make column filtering works. I'm using the `$_REQUEST` variable but I don't know how to use it correctly. 
Please please, someone help me... I'm so stuck here. T_T

Some codes below are apparently omitted.

**php block and html**

```php
<?php
use Jiwon\Byapps\Models\AppsData;

function onStart()
{
    $this['tableName'] = 'BYAPPS_apps_data';
    $this['fields'] = "idx|app_id|app_name|app_ver|byapps_ver|app_process|script_popup|custom_etc|apps_type|start_time|end_time";
}
?>

<table id="datalist" class="table table-striped mb-3" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>app id</th>
                <th>app name</th>
                <th>ver</th>
                <th>BV</th>
                <th>process</th>
                <th>SCRIPT</th>
                <th>custom</th>
                <th>OS</th>
                <th>start</th>
                <th>end</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

**javascript part**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableId = "datalist";

  $('#' + tableId + ' thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#' + tableId + ' thead');
  $('#' + tableId + ' thead tr:eq(1) th').not('th.chk').each(function(i){
      var title = $(this).text();
      $(this).html( '<input type="text" class="filter-input" placeholder="'+title+'" data-column="'+i+'"/>' );
  });

  var table = $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
       ajax: {
          url: '/ajax',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            tb: '{{ tableName|raw() }}',
            fd: '{{ fields|raw() }}'
          },
          error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
      },
      columnDefs: [
       {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
                'selectRow': true
          }
       }
     ],
     select: {
         'style': 'multi'
      },
      paging: true,
      pageLength: 50,
});

  $('.filter-input').on( 'keyup click', function () {
    var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
    var v = $(this).val();
    table.column(i).search(v).draw();
  });
});
```

**server-side php file**

```php
function onStart()
{
   $table = $_POST['tb'];
   $length = $_POST['length'];
   $start = $_POST['start'];
   $fields = explode("|", $_POST['fd']);
   $searchVar = $_POST['search']['value'];

   $requestData= $_REQUEST;

   if ($searchVar != '') {
     $result = DB::table($table)
               ->where('app_name', 'like', '%'.$searchVar.'%')
               ->orWhere('app_id', 'like', '%'.$searchVar.'%')
               ->orderBy('idx', 'desc')
               ->get();
   } else {
     $result = DB::table($table)
               ->skip($start)
               ->limit($length)
               ->orderBy('idx', 'desc')
               ->get();
   }

   $data = array();

   foreach($result as $row) {
      $sub_array = array();

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {

         if (strpos($fields[$i], 'time')) {
           $sub_array[] = gmdate("Y-m-d", $row->{$fields[$i]});
         } else if ($fields[$i] == 'app_process') {
           $arrProcess = [
               1 => 'ready', 2 => 'go', 3 => 'ing', 4 => 'denial',
               5 => 'retry', 6 => 'reexam', 7 => 'complete', 8 => 'stopped',
               9 => 'expired', 10 => 'valid'
            ];

           foreach ($arrProcess as $key=>$val) {
             if($row->{$fields[$i]} == $key) {
                $sub_array[] = $arrProcess[$key];
             }
           }
         } else if ($fields[$i] == 'script_popup') {
             if ($row->{$fields[$i]} == 'Y') {
               $sub_array[] = 'installed';
             } else {
               $sub_array[] = '-';
             }
         } else if ($fields[$i] == 'custom_etc') {
            if ($row->{$fields[$i]} != '') {
              $sub_array[] .= $row->{$fields[$i]}." custom";
            } else {
              $sub_array[] = '-';
            }
         } else {
            $sub_array[] = $row->{$fields[$i]};
         }
      }
      $data[] = $sub_array;
   }

   $output = array(
     "draw" => intval($_POST['draw']),
     "recordsTotal" => DB::table($table)->count(),
     "recordsFiltered" => DB::table($table)->count(),
     "data" => $data,
   );

   echo json_encode($output);
}
```

I also tried this below. but it logs infinite loop...X( 
Plz somebody help me..!_!

```php
for ($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
    if ($_POST["columns"][$i]["search"]["value"] != '') {
        trace_log($_POST["columns"][$i]);
        if (in_array($_POST["columns"][$i]["search"]["value"], $data[$j]) != false) {
          trace_log($j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, what is the actual question here? Is something wrong? Do you get errors? DO you get incorrect output?? Please give us something to go on here

Comment: I see one line using `$REQUEST` as  you mention above, `$requestData= $_REQUEST;` But I dont see any code that then uses `$requestData`??? So I still am not sure what your problem is!

Comment: @RiggsFolly  The problem is I don't know what to do with the ``$_REQUEST``. Should I use it like ``$_GET[search]``? I already tried it but I couldn't get the results.

Comment: Do you know what `$_REQUEST` contains? Why do you think you would need to use it?

Comment: I know it contains the column search values. Like ``$_REQUEST[column][0][search][value]``.